# Are there journals in science communication (STEM field) that allow technical notes?

Tags: journals, chemistry, science-communication

I've written a small piece of software which allows users to gain easy access to nice visualization of computed chemical reactions. It's great having such videos in a presentation in a professional environment but it's also nice for teaching or just science communication, even simple videos get quite a lot of views on youtube and they can be used for sparking interest in STEM careers.

I was thinking about writing a small tutorial about how to produce data to visualize using freeware and how to handle the software to make such videos in addition to providing the software. Since I'm already producing a manuscrip I thought I might be able to publish it rather than just putting it on a preprint server.

However, it's out of scope for the chemistry journals I've looked at and also the chemistry education journal. I thought about science communication journals (terrible search phrase) but all that I could find are reporting on research regarding science communication and tools helping with science communication don't seem to fit.

Any idea where such an article could be published?

Comment: For physics, I'd say the American Association of Physics Teachers has a journal going back quite some ways (at least the 1960's). It looks like the American Association of Chemistry Teachers (teachchemistry.org) has recently launched a periodical and would probably love some content.

Comment: This might be off-topic, but: in [Astronomy & Astrophysics](https://www.aanda.org/author-information) there are sections 12. _Atomic, molecular, and nuclear data_, and 15. _Numerical methods and codes_. If you can connect/find applications (even remotely) of your work to astro, you might consider submitting there. Or, if you find it unfeasible, maybe some info in the link will give you some ideas about how/what/where to look in your field. In the worst case, my comment will be just useless (sorry).